# Regex extract numer into group

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, python, regex

I have simple html code:

```
<span class="someclass" title="4.5 stars"></span>
```

or it could be:

```
<span class="someclass" title="5 stars"></span>
```

I used `((\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)) star` but it extracted me 3 groups, I need one with numeric value.

How can I extract 4.5 and 5 in both strings using Regex in one group?

Thanks!

Comment: Python, c#,  asp.net and js? What are you using?

Comment: As most people do, I would suggest you to use Html Agility Pack for .net http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the inner parentheses:

```
(\d+\.\d+|\d+) star
```

Also, you may wish to consider using an HTML parser to extract the attributes first rather than applying the regular expression directly to the raw HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can make groups non capturing by adding a ?: after the opening bracket like this

```
((?:\d+\.\d+)|(?:\d+)) star
```

but your inner brackets are not needed in your case.

You can rewrite your expression to

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) star
```

Answer (score 0):

In python it could be done this way:

```
import re

txt = '<span class="someclass" title="4.5 stars"></span>, <span class="someclass" title="5 stars"></span>'
re.findall(r'\d+[.]\d+|\d+', txt)

['4.5', '5']
```